# How do you style primaryText and secondaryText differently for <MenuItem />

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I feel like there would have some default option to apply styling to one prop or the other but I don't see anything in the docs that would allow me to do that.

There's a `style` prop that I can use, but that applies styles to the entire component. Also the `innerDivStyle` prop only styles the enclosing wrapper div, not one or the other props/divs of the text itself.

```
<MenuItem className="foobar" style={{color:'red'}} innerDivStyle={{color:'blue'}} primaryText="My Primary text" secondaryText="My Secondary text" />
```

This component Renders to this:

```
<div>
  <span class="foobar" tabindex="0" style="border: 10px; box-sizing: border-box; display: block; font-family: Roboto, sans-serif; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); cursor: pointer; text-decoration: none; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; outline: none; font-size: 16px; font-weight: inherit; position: relative; color: red; line-height: 48px; transition: all 450ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1) 0ms; min-height: 48px; white-space: nowrap; background: none;">
    <div>
      <div style="margin-left: 0px; padding: 0px 16px; position: relative; color: blue;">
        <div style="float: right;">My Secondary Text</div>
        <div>My Primary Text</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </span>
</div>
```

Which doesn't seem to have any way to differentiate the two divs.
Of course I could probably use div:first-child or something but I feel like that would be a workaround to a fundamental problem or something I'm clearly missing.

Material-UI version: 0.16.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So even though there's no example in the docs that uses this technique, I realized that the `primaryText` and `secondaryText` props expect a `node` object. This is usually just a string in almost every example but it can also be just a straight up element.

This is how you can style a separate prop.

```
<MenuItem primaryText="My Primary Text" 
  secondaryText={<span style={{  color: 'blue'  }}>My Secondary Text</span>} />
```

Answer (score 0):

Inline css is not recommended anymore, use isomorphic style-loader to embed css from a separate file.
Check : https://www.npmjs.com/package/isomorphic-style-loader